# Full version of Cameron Martin theorem for Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I’m looking for a version of the Cameron Martin theorem for the Brownian motion under random shifts. Here is the precise statement:

Let $\mathbb P$ be Wiener measure on $\Omega := C[0, 1]$. Given a $C[0, 1] $ valued random variable $F$, define the translation map $T_F: \Omega \to \Omega$ by $T_F (\omega) = \omega + F(\omega)$, and denote the pushforward of $\mathbb P$ under this map by $T_F^{\ast} \, \mathbb P $.

Denote by $W^{1, 2}$ the space of absolutely continuous functions on $[0, 1]$ with derivative in $L^2$.

> **Theorem:** $\mathbb Q$ is equivalent to $\mathbb P$ if and only if $\mathbb Q = T_F ^\ast \, \mathbb P$ for some $F$ such that $F(0) = 0$ and $F \in W^{1, 2}$ almost surely.

My questions are two-fold:

1. Is this statement true?
2. If so, where can I find a proof?

So far the statements I could find were only for deterministic
shifts $F$, these are what is usually called the Cameron Martin theorem
for Brownian motion. On the other hand, statements of Girsanov’s theorem deal with random shifts, but typically are concerned with the Radon Nikodym derivative, and are silent on the interpretation as shifts by $W^{1, 2}$ processes.

Comment: Did you check the monograph of Lipster and Shiryaev? They proved various results of this type characterizing measures absolutely cts wrt bm. They give a structure theorem for such measures of similar flavor to what you posted above. See this chapter: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-13043-8_8

Comment: Oh, I have not seen that - seems pretty comprehensive indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\varphi$ be a smooth function such that $\varphi(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $\varphi(x)=1$ for $x\geq 1$, and $0\leq\varphi(x)\leq 1$ else. If $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are is the first times $B_t$ hits $1,2$ respectively, and $M$ is a maximum of the $B_t$ on $[0,1]$, put $F_t=-M\varphi(\frac{t-\tau_1}{\tau_2-\tau_1})$. Then, $\sup (B_t+F_t)\leq 2$ almost surely, hence $\mathbb{P}$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Ah, so it is not true I see. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @NateRiver, I don't know though whether $\mathbb{Q}$ is always a.c. w.r.t $\mathbb{P}$, or whether the converse implication holds, but I would be very surprised if it did.

Comment: @Kostya_I see https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/lecture-25-girsanov-theore/ for a "converse" Girsanov